# Problema con cálculo en python

Tags: python

hice la siguiente función para hacer un cálculo en python:

```
def calcular():
    valores= int(entrada1.get()), int(entrada2.get()), int(entrada3.get()), int(entrada4.get()), int(entrada5.get()), int(entrada6.get()), int(entrada7.get()), int(entrada8.get()), int(entrada9.get()), int(entrada10.get())
    valorAlto= max(int(float(entrada1.get())), int(float(entrada2.get())), int(float(entrada3.get())), int(float(entrada4.get())), int(entrada5.get()), int(entrada6.get()), int(entrada7.get()), int(entrada8.get()), int(entrada9.get()), int(entrada10.get()))
    valormedio= (int(float(entrada1.get())), int(float(entrada2.get())), int(float(entrada3.get())), int(float(entrada4.get())), int(entrada5.get()), int(entrada6.get()), int(entrada7.get()), int(entrada8.get()), int(entrada9.get()), int(entrada10.get())) / valores.count
    valorBajo= min(int(float(entrada1.get())), int(float(entrada2.get())), int(float(entrada3.get())), int(float(entrada4.get())), int(entrada5.get()), int(entrada6.get()), int(entrada7.get()), int(entrada8.get()), int(entrada9.get()), int(entrada10.get()))
    return var3.set(valorBajo), var.set(valormedio), var2.set(valorAlto)
```

Soy nuevo en esto y quiero saber cómo hago para que en caso de que en el programa no se introduzca alguna o varias de las entradas, haga el cálculo usando los valores dados y que los divida entre el número de entradas introducidas.

Comment: Entiendo que `entrada1`, `entrada2` etc son _widgets_ de alguna interfaz gráfica (quizás con Tk, no?). Lo adecuado sería tener todas esas variables en una lista, para de ese modo poder hacer bucles sobre ellas. Por ejemplo podrías crear otra lista con los valores leidos, y después "filtrarla" para eliminar los valores vacíos. Finalmente harías tus cálculos con las listas resultantes (el valor medio por cierto es la suma entre la la longitud de la lista).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando empiezas a nombrar tus variables con número, es señal de que debes usar una lista.

Tenemos que entrada1, entrada2, ... son objetos de algún tipo con una función `get` que retorna un valor numérico (entero o flotante da igual).

En estos casos, declaramos una lista que contenga todos los objetos:

```
entradas = [entrada1, entrada2, entrada3, entrada4, entrada5]
```

y luego aplicamos compresión de listas para extraer el valor de cada elemento y generar una nueva lista con ella:

```
valores = [x.get() for x in entradas]
```

Esto nos da una lista de valores, que ahora podemos usar con las funciones nativas de Python:

```
valorAlto = max(entradas)
valorMedio = sum(valores) / len(valores)
valorBajo = min(entradas)
```

La función `max` calcula el máximo de una lista. La función `min`, el mínimo.

Para calcular el valor medio, sumamos con `sum` todos los elementos y dividimos por el número de elementos.

Finalmente, dejamos intacta la última linea

return var3.set(valorBajo), var.set(valormedio), var2.set(valorAlto)

Comment: Muchas graciaaas, eres un Chad :D